# Error while running npm install -g composer-cli on Window 10

Tags: node.js, npm, hyperledger-composer, node-gyp

I'm running command  npm install -g composer-cli but facing below error:

gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:336:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\vb0094005\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\composer-cli\node_modules\node-report
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\composer-cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-report@2.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-report@2.2.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

I tried everything metioned in article : https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
but no luck.

Node version: v8.11.1
npm version : 5.6.0
node-gyp : v3.8.0

Please help to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

This platform is not supported at this time - see https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html. I recommend you use a hypervisor such as VirtualBox for Windows 10 Professional environment - the built-in Hyper-V support allows to run a Linux virtual machine where you can install Hyperledger Composer. Also we recommend using Ubuntu 16.04 in the VM, as this is the level we test with most.

If you insist on Windows, someone has shared some resources for Windows install (provided as-is) -> https://davidkel.github.io/docs/Windows/Intro.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer Paul. I started it on Ubuntu 16.04 and working fine :)